# I want to make the layout border like it shown in the below image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

here in this picture there is a triangle border on the bottom border of the layout. I have made the border but i am not getting how to make that triangle mark in the border. please check my code that i am sharing.

```
enter code here
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="@color/light_grey" />
<gradient android:startColor="@color/white" android:endColor="@color/white"
    />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

This is my code please check.

Comment: What about using a 9 patch?

Comment: You should use 9 patch image.

Comment: I have no idea about that can you tell me anything that i can do in xml so i will get that layout border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bob Malooga mentioned you can use 9 patch image with the whole "bubble" layout or you can draw your own "bubble".

If you don't want to use 9 patch image, than you can achieve your layout as i mention below.

Triangel Drawable layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Overlay Fragment layout (I used your "bubble" background As the TextViews background):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:background="@drawable/your_bubble_bg"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/triangle" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image: result of the Overlay fragment layout code]

You can also change the triangle shape to custom triangle drawable and use that as imageViews "src".

After that your layout code will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:background="@drawable/triangle_b"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_custom_triangle_drawable" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can achive it with one drawable only!

Background layout (merged_bubble_bg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="33dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@color/grey_light" />
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:startColor="@color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />

        </shape>

    </item>
    <item
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="34dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:right="32dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The above code in use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:background="@drawable/merged_bubble_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks petin for the answer its working awesome.

Comment: Thanks @petin for the answer its working awesome thanks....